# Index rebuild batch sizing setting?

Tags: content-search, indexing, index, settings

I need to change the size of the batches during the index rebuild. The most suitable setting I've found is `ContentSearch.Update.BatchSize` with the description:

> The size of document batch before flushing to the database.

Am I right that this setting is applicable not only for updating an index, but on rebuild, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

This settings is a general setting that is used by `SolrBatchUpdateContext` class.

It's used both for partial updates and for full index rebuild.

With that setting (and `ContentSearch.Update.BatchModeEnabled` setting set to `true` ) you can specify how big should be the batches of documents sent to Solr.

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.Update.BatchModeEnabled" value="true" />
```

`BatchModeEnabled` is set to `true` by default and `BatchSize` has default value `100` (or in some version it's `50` if it's not filled in config).